# Markdown within yaml / yaml multi-line escape sequence?

Tags: yaml, markdown, cdata, string-literals

Is it possible to store unescaped markdown documents in yaml? I've tested

```
key:|+ 
    markdown text block that could have any combination of line breaks, >, -, :, ', " etc etc.
```

This does not work. I need something like CDATA or python style triple-quotes for yamal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In literal style of scalar type (what you used in example) line brakes needs still to be "escaped" (in this case intended correctly).

And you can only have printable characters.

I am not fammiliar with markdown, but in case you would need to save unprintable characters, you would definitelly to escape them.

From [Yaml specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2770814):

> To ensure readability, YAML streams
>   use only the printable subset of the
>   Unicode character set. The allowed
>   character range explicitly excludes
>   the C0 control block #x0-#x1F (except
>   for TAB #x9, LF #xA, and CR #xD which
>   are allowed), DEL #x7F, the C1 control
>   block #x80-#x9F (except for NEL #x85
>   which is allowed), the surrogate
>   block #xD800-#xDFFF, #xFFFE, and #xFFFF.
>
> On input, a YAML processor must accept
>   all Unicode characters except those
>   explicitly excluded above.
>
> On output, a YAML processor must only
>   produce acceptable characters. Any
>   excluded characters must be presented
>   using escape sequences.